# "Error: message file too big" Is the limit on outgoing or receiving end?

Tags: mail-server

A client is trying to send a rather large email but it gets bounced back with the following message:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at server2.hysir.net.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<maria@laeknastodin.is>:
157.157.98.19 failed after I sent the message.
Remote host said: 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big
```

I've checked and there is no limit on outgoing mail size on our end and this ip address i.e 157.157.98.19 is the ip for the receiving mail server, am I right to assume the mail server for laeknastodin.is is denying the mail due to its size rather than our smtp refusing to send?

Comment: Exactly that is occurring. (And hysir.net is an intermediate transit system in the mail chain it seems.)

Comment: postconf -e "message_size_limit = 20480000"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Remote host said: 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big
```

The error message clearly states that receiving host is limiting the message size. If you check with telnet you can see that the limit configured on the target host is 20 MB (20480000 bytes)

```
telnet 157.157.98.19 25
Trying 157.157.98.19...
Connected to 157.157.98.19.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.laeknastodin.is ESMTP Postfix
EHLO example.com
250-mail.laeknastodin.is
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000     <----------- 20 MB limit
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Comment: how were you able to telnet that host, it just times out for me

Comment: works fine here - maybe your provider is blocking connections to port 25 outgoing, lots of dial-up/residential networks are not able to directly connect to port 25 on outside hosts (spam prevention)

Comment: Ofcourse, thats exactly it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to clarify: the limit is not 20 MB but about 19,53 MB, since 20 MB = 20971520 Bytes and 20480000 Bytes = 19.53125 MB

Comment: A special thanks for providing a command to check the actual limit!